# "Sender action failed" When reacting to facebook message

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-debugger

I am using facebook api to react messages in messenger. This is the api POST request I am using

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/<PAGE-ID>/messages?recipient={id:<Pariticipant_ID>}&sender_action=react&payload={message_id:m_sVNX5t0U5gArMtgF2Dr26p5dVVsRueGmj101HP625pxXCZXRr6HtLeLonjV5eFKp44MXhELnNWrz50k6Upl8zg,reaction:love}&access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

After making the post request I am getting  "Sender action failed" as response.(Please find the complete response below)

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Sender action failed",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "error_subcode": 2018048,
        "fbtrace_id": "AjwcP68lSlj9seauOxeV_Tl"
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there any way to send reactions to messages?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to make this work?

Comment: Do you know what the issue was?

Comment: @Daan still no solution

Comment: @YasanthaMihiran thanks for getting back to me. I think the API is currently only working for Instagram direct messages and only to send out a heart reaction. That's the only thing I got working with it.